# Injecting Entity Manager automatically in JPA 2.0

Tags: jpa

I have a very strange problem with a JSF 2.1 project that I am working on
I am using IBM Rational Application Developer for WebSphere Software version 9.1, and WebSphere Application Server version 8.5.5
I have created a dynamic JSF web project with JSF version 2.1, and an EJB project containing my Entities and EJBs, with EJB version 3.1 and JPA 2, and I have included the CDI (Content and Dependency Injection) Facet to both the JPA and JSF projects.

The project that I'm working on is a simple news module where I am supposed to perform add, search, update and delete operations on News Items and Authors.

Everything works fine when I manually set the Entity Manager, but when I don't set the Entity Manager manually and leave it to be injected automatically, I get a `NullPointerException` whenever I try to access the Entity Manager.

My code is as follows

My `persistence.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="newsProjectPersistence" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jndi/NewsProj</jta-data-source>
        <class>model.User</class>
        <class>model.Address</class>
        <class>model.Author</class>
        <class>model.NewsItem</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My [Controller.java](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0_LQ9oz0KxucXdjalFXWVI5NEU/view?usp=sharing) class (The EJB)

I have two JSP pages, Login.jsp and Index.jsp

My [Login.jsp](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0_LQ9oz0KxuWnJQdElQbDI5ekE/view?usp=sharing)

My [Login.java](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0_LQ9oz0KxubVNTVDhWOTZkTk0/view?usp=sharing) (pagecode/managed bean)

My [Index.jsp](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0_LQ9oz0KxuN2VwNWFGemxOMnc/view?usp=sharing)

My [Index.java](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0_LQ9oz0KxudmF0YXFRREFKMk0/view?usp=sharing) (pagecode/managed bean)

And the exception is:

```
        [7/24/16 16:53:32:544 EET] 00000092 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper inject SRVE8042E: An internal error caused the reference context that enables injection to not be initialized properly.
[7/24/16 16:53:35:765 EET] 00000092 ErrorPageWrit E   An exception occurred
        javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.apache.jasper.el.JspELException: /Login.jsp(63,9) '#{pc_Login.doBtnLoginAction}' java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.faces.component._MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.invoke(_MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.java:96)
        at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:100)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:120)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:973)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:275)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1285)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:711)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:34)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:172)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:119)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:909)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
    Caused by: org.apache.jasper.el.JspELException: /Login.jsp(63,9) '#{pc_Login.doBtnLoginAction}' java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.jasper.el.JspMethodExpression.invoke(JspMethodExpression.java:79)
        at javax.faces.component._MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.invoke(_MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.java:88)
        ... 31 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at beans.Controller.checkAuthentication(Controller.java:157)
        at pagecode.Login.doBtnLoginAction(Login.java:72)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:268)
        at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
        at org.apache.jasper.el.JspMethodExpression.invoke(JspMethodExpression.java:70)
        ... 32 more
```

I have tried to provide all the information so I can get any help with this, since I have tried everything I found online and asked a lot and everything didn't work.

The exception that I get is mainly because the reference context that enables injection is not initialized properly, and I have no idea why. As far as I know, I have done everything right so any help would be appreciated

[EDIT]: It is such that when I use `emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("newsProjectPersistence");` and `em = emf.createEntityManager();` (when I set the Entity Manager manually), everything runs fine, but when I remove these lines as shown in `Controller.java` I get a `NullPointerException` whenever I try to access the Entity Manager.

Also, as I understand, I don't need to call `em.flush()` in order to reflect changes on the database and that changes should be flushed automatically. However, this is not the case here. when I set the entity manager manually and all database operations are working, I need to flush manually in order to reflect changes on the database. I don't know whether this has to do with the fact that automatic injection isn't enabled.

Comment: You get some error ... we don't see it. You say it relates to some Entity ... we don't see it.

Comment: There is a lot of confusion here.  First your settings show a "RESOURCE_LOCAL" transaction type, yet you've stated the persistence unit is to use a JTA-Datasource.  You also use native SQL queries all over the place instead of JPA, even for updates, so who knows if you've setup CRUD JPA options correctly.  For instance, you do know that createNativeQuery("update authnews an set deleted = 1 where an.newsid="+ itemToDelete.getId());  will update the database fine, but your object model will be left showing the stale data?

Comment: You also when creating an Author add in a new Address, but then assign that address an ID based on a query to the address table.  You are not allowed to persist a  detached entity.

Comment: @Chris I have updated my code, and I got everything to work when I set the entity manager manually. However, I still have the same problem with injecting the entity manager. So if you can, please check the changed that I made and let me know if I'm still doing anything wrong.
And I do realize that I am using a lot of native SQL queries, but it's only because I am a beginner in JPA and JSF and I'm trying to get things working.

Comment: I do know that the idea behind JPA is not having to write native SQL queries, but I can replace the native queries by using em.persist() and passing the updated object as a parameter. I can do this later once I fix the main problem which is injecting the Entity Manager
And regarding your comment on deletion, I only show records where deleted == '0' so that works fine